# H2 database: RuntimeException: rowcount remaining=3 SYS

Tags: java, database, h2

I got this error when trying to get a connection with my H2 database in my Java app.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: rowcount remaining=3 SYS" [50000-170]
```

Googling it I found some indications that my database may have corrupted. So, as the H2 docs[1] says, there is a recovery tool to restore corrupted databases by executing this on command line:

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Recover
```

The problem is that I got a lot of errors then:

```
...
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Error: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
...
```

The `.sql` file generated starts with this line:

```
// error: org.h2.message.DbException: Encryption error in file "C:/test/testdata.h2.db" [90049-170]
```

And then continues with thousands of commented lines of error:

```
-- pageSize: 898638978 writeVersion: 76 readVersion: 89
-- ERROR: page size; using 2048
-- head 1: writeCounter: -6011171782251773310 log -1342746462:2067436818/892099140 crc 1787578286 (expected: -1599867117)
-- head 2: writeCounter: -5218598065026680826 log 1157017086:-975711878/-1815014411 crc 1294221878 (expected: -1302067923)
-- log 0:0/0
```

and so on...

Does anyone know how I can recover my database?

[1]http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#using_recover_tool

Comment: What is the database URL?

Comment: @ThomasMueller jdbc:h2:file:C:\test\testdata;CIPHER=XTEA;AUTOCOMMIT=OFF;WRITE_DELAY=300;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_MODE=1;FILE_LOCK=SOCKET

Comment: In that case, you first need to decrypt the database file (using the ChangeFileEncryption tool) before you can use the Recover tool. That's why you got "Encryption error".

Comment: @ThomasMueller I tried running ChangeFileEncryption as you mentioned but it gives me this error: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3` on `ChangeFileEncryption.runTool(ChangeFileEncryption.java:74)`

Comment: java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.ChangeFileEncryption -cipher XTEA -decrypt "my password"

Comment: Please as a new question. I think you didn't specify the password by the way.